# Issue with HTTPS Interception in Electron App Using http-mitm-proxy: HTTP Works, HTTPS Does not

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-packager, electron-forge

I'm developing an Electron application that uses the `http-mitm-proxy` (https://github.com/joeferner/node-http-mitm-proxy) library for intercepting and handling web requests. My application is set up to create a custom proxy to intercept web traffic. So far, I've successfully managed to intercept HTTP traffic, but I'm encountering issues when trying to intercept HTTPS traffic.

The core problem seems to be that while HTTP requests are handled perfectly, HTTPS requests are not going through as expected. After some research and debugging, I've concluded that the likely culprit is the SSL certificate: it appears I need to install or trust the SSL certificate generated by `http-mitm-proxy` within the Electron browser for HTTPS interception to work correctly.

Below is the full code snippet of my current setup:

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow, session } = require('electron');
const Proxy = require('http-mitm-proxy').Proxy;
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const proxy = new Proxy();
const logFilePath = path.join(__dirname, 'requests.log'); // Path to the log file

app.on('ready', async () => {
    // Start the MITM proxy
    proxy.listen({ port: 8088, sslCaDir: path.join(__dirname, 'certs') }, () => {
        console.log('MITM proxy listening on port 8080');
    });

    // Intercept and log all requests to a file
    proxy.onRequest((ctx, callback) => {
        const requestDetails = `Received request: ${ctx.clientToProxyRequest.method} ${ctx.clientToProxyRequest.headers.host}${ctx.clientToProxyRequest.url}\n`;
        console.log('Request intercepted:', requestDetails);

        // Append the request details to the log file
        fs.appendFile(logFilePath, requestDetails, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Error writing to log file:', err);
            }
        });

        return callback();
    });

    // Ensure the default session is ready before setting the proxy
    const proxyURL = 'http=127.0.0.1:8080;https=127.0.0.1:8088';
    await session.defaultSession.setProxy({ proxyRules: proxyURL });

    createWindow();
});

function createWindow() {
    // Create a BrowserWindow instance
    const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: false,
            // Important: Use the default session for the proxy settings
        }
    });

    // Load a specific website using the proxy
    // mainWindow.loadURL('http://example.com'); //works
    mainWindow.loadURL('https://example.com'); //dont work

}
```

Comment: The big problem is that i have no idea how to install the certificate 
on the github it says: https://github.com/joeferner/node-http-mitm-proxy
SSL
Using node-forge allows the automatic generation of SSL certificates within the proxy. After running your app you will find options.sslCaDir + '/certs/ca.pem' which can be imported to your browser, phone, etc.

i know how to do this in chrome and in windows but not in electron